# Java issue with saving file with new name

Tags: java, save, bufferedimage

I am writing a program whch requires me to save a BufferedImage with a new name. I can get the save dialog and stuff to work. I can even save the file with the same name it had before. I just can't figure out how a user can enter a new name in the save dialog and have the file saved under that name. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
if (chooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", chooser.getSelectedFile());
```

Comment: Thank you, really. But I'm having a difficult time deciphering that site.

Answer (score 1):

Read [`JFileChooser's getSelectedFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29) method javadoc carefully.

Quoting:

> Returns the selected file. This can be
>   set either by the programmer via
>   setFile or by a user action, such as
>   either typing the filename into the UI
>   or selecting the file from a list in
>   the UI.